# When formatting floats in DataGridView to a certain decimal, cannot copy full number

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm creating a Windows Form application, more or less acting as the interface to a SQL db for our users. I want to format the floats to 1 or 2 decimal places when they look at the form, but I also want to have the ability to copy the DataGridView out to excel with the full float if they desire.

For example, if I'm formatting rows to be a percent with 1 decimal place I'll use

```
DataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "P1";
```

This looks great in the Form, but when I copy the DataGridView to the Clipboard, it copies just 1 decimal place, even if the float from the DataTable I'm using as a source has more decimal places.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to copy the unformatted data to Clipboard. I've even considered making a Copy Button which accesses an invisible DataGridView which is unformatted, but I'd like users to be able to Ctrl-C from the visible, formatted DataGridView.

Any ideas? Even letting me know I'm out of luck would help, as I'll give up on the Ctrl-C functionality and just create a separate Copy function. Thanks.

Comment: You to get the number from the data Source you can hook the key down event to get when the user hits Ctrl-C and then get the DataSource value to send tot eh ClipBoard I hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, N4TKD idea is not bad: you can even avoid the CTRL+C, by instructing the user to perform certain action in order to get a custom copying. For example: you can extend the code in my sample by also adding the copying functionality at runtime; that is, when pressing enter on a given cell, the number format would be automatically converted to the desired version and would also be copied to the clipboard.

Comment: @varocarbas cool point I will add that to my toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to allow users to copy something different than what is being displayed (1-decimal values). A workaround to get what you want might be enabling two different "modes" to show the information in the cells: short and long format. And adding a user-friendly way to switch between both modes; for example: pressing "Enter" in a cell. Sample code:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        if (shortMode)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[curRow].DefaultCellStyle.Format = ""; //Number with all the decimals
            shortMode = false;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[curRow].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "P1"; //Number as percentage with 1 decimal
            shortMode = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `shortMode` is a boolean variable declared globally and `curRow` is the row you want to change.

Comment: Cool, yeah that looks useful. I wonder if it makes sense to look for a Ctrl key press and try to change the formatting in time for when they press Ctrl-C. The timing may not work tho.

Comment: @PaypahTowels I have written a comment above right now on these lines: you might include copying to the clipboard here. In this way the user would have just to press enter in a cell and he would get two things: the desired format + data (in the desired format) in the clipboard.

Comment: @PaypahTowels just add: Clipboard.SetText("value to be copied")

Comment: @PaypahTowels and by answering to the CTRL-C question: it can also be done (change Keys.Enter to the key(s) you want), although might give some problems because of referring to a key combination which has already associated a functionality (also it would be more complicated making sure that two keys are pressed instead a single one). I think that Enter (or any other single key) and the extended functionality of copying to the clipboard delivers the best solution for what you want.